# error C2783: could not deduce template argument for structure argument

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, initialization

I am facing error C2783.
I reproduce error with similar structure test case.
Here is test case:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace ns1 {
    template <class T> class class_1 {};
}

namespace ns2 {
    using namespace ns1;
    template <typename T> inline ns1::class_1<T> myfunc();

    template<typename T>
    inline ns1::class_1<T> myfunc() {
            int a,b;
            std::cin>>a;
            std::cin>>b;
            if(a<b) return true;
            else return false;
    }

}


namespace ns3 {
struct myStruct {
    ns1::class_1<double> var1;
    ns1::class_1<double> var2;
    myStruct ( const ns1::class_1<double>& cl0= ns2::myfunc<double>(),
                    const ns1::class_1<double>& cl1= ns2::myfunc<double>()): var1(cl0), var2(cl1) {};
    };
}
```

Error is :
error C2783: 'ns1::class_1 ns2::myfunc(void)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T'

Also i wonder why its giving error for line 27 (cl0) but not line 28 (for cl1)? 
If I try to use this on some function its works fine only giving error when using in structure arguments.

Comment: line `if(a<b) return true;` should already produce an error. You've got no conversion from `bool` to `ns1::class_1`.

Comment: @jrok: I tried to compile this with VS10 but i get only C2783. any way that thing is different in my code i made this just as to reproduce error with similar structure.

Comment: Well, the structure is not similar enough for me as I can't reprocude your error.

Comment: for you its compiling fine? i just put this code in header file and include that header file in just a simple cpp with having only main (not using anything) and on compiling its giving the error. Please let me know what setting you did?

Comment: No, it doesn't compile for me - see my first comment.

Comment: @jork: (this might be very silly and obvious for you if so sorry for that) If we don't include in cpp then there is no error.

Comment: jork: ok can you please do a small modification? add `public:
  class_1 (int a, int b){}`
 in class_1 and then in **replace if-else** condition with `pod::class_1 c(a,b);
  return c;` if this works for you let me know i will edit question. Thx for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a compiler bug. If you replace the contents of `myfunc` with valid code (as suggested), it still doesn't work. For a description, status (and acknowledgement) of the bug, see [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759770/error-c2783-in-function-default-argument). You might try to use a helper type to get argument deduction (which works):

```
namespace ns1 {
    template <class T> class class_1 {
    public: class_1 (int a, int b){}
    };
}

namespace ns2 {
    template<class T> struct deduction_helper{};

    using namespace ns1;
    template <typename T> inline ns1::class_1<T> myfunc(deduction_helper<T>);

    template<typename T>
    inline ns1::class_1<T> myfunc(deduction_helper<T>) {
        int a,b;
        std::cin>>a;
        std::cin>>b;
        ns1::class_1<T> c(a,b); return c;
    }

}


namespace ns3 {
    struct myStruct {
        ns1::class_1<double> var1;
        ns1::class_1<double> var2;

        myStruct ( const ns1::class_1<double>& cl0= ns2::myfunc(ns2::deduction_helper<double>()),
                   const ns1::class_1<double>& cl1= ns2::myfunc(ns2::deduction_helper<double>())
                 ): var1(cl0), var2(cl1) {};
    };
}

int main()
{
    ns3::myStruct x;
}
```

N.B. as the helper type resides in `ns2`, you could use ADL instead of qualifying the name `myfunc`.